# Multiple tabs in Safari

Tags: imac

In Safari on my iMac there are tabs open for just about every website I been for along time. I keep closing them individually, but more keep appearing. I have recently upgraded to Maverick

Comment: Hi, and welcome to AskDifferent. What is your question? Are you wondering how to close all of the tabs at once? You can close all tabs except for the current one by holding down option-command-W...

Answer (score 1):

You can go to System Preferences → General and tick "Close windows when quitting an application".

When ticked, open tabs will not be restored when you re-open Safari and therefore not "build up". So just shut down Safari from time to time (cmd + q).